# Match date pattern in table cells with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table with cells that contain dates that follow a particular pattern. When a cell contains a date, all cells in the same column are dates of the same pattern. How can I use jQuery to match the format and return the column? Here is a sample table that demonstrates the pattern:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------+
| Type  | Compiled? |    Modified (CDT)     |     Created (CDT)     | Priority |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------+
| Fancy | yes       | Oct 18, 2013 16:17:00 | Oct 08, 2013 05:50:32 |       75 |
| Fancy | yes       | Oct 18, 2013 16:16:28 | Oct 18, 2013 15:46:05 |       75 |
| Fancy | yes       | Oct 18, 2013 16:15:25 | Oct 17, 2013 19:04:51 |       75 |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------+
```

Comment: so you would like to retrieve all the cells from this column ? You can do that even with no parsing at all since you know all the cells that belong to one column have the same pattern ..

Comment: @f00bar There will be other tables with unpredictable column headings and column orders.

Comment: Is the date pattern always the same ?

Comment: @f00bar Yes, it's always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along these lines:

```
$('table td').filter(function () { return /.../.test($(this).html()); }).map(function () { return $(this).index(); } );
```

...where /.../ is a regex matching the date format you are looking for. This will return you an array of column indexes containing at least one match for that pattern. It's not a unique list. The following regex will work if you're just looking for a pattern don't absolutely need to make sure it's a valid date...

```
/^\w{3}\s\d+,\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/
```

(This will match the 99 o'clock on the 45th of Ziptember, so maybe get a better regex.)

I'll break down that dense line a bit to illustrate things a bit better:

```
date_filter = function () { return /^\w{3}\s\d+,\s\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test($(this).html())}

map_td_to_index = function () { return $(this).index(); }

console.log($('table td').filter(date_filter).map(map_td_to_index));
```

Edit: removed erroneous usage of $.unique, which is only for arrays of DOM elements. You could make use of something like this:

```
$.fn.extend({ unique: function() 
              {
                arr = $.makeArray(this);
                return $.grep(arr, function(elem, idx) 
                                   {
                                     return $.inArray(elem, arr, idx + 1) === -1;
                                   }); 
              } 
            });
```

Then just call `.unique()` after the call to `map()`.

Comment: I would test against the `text()` not `html()` of the cell, inside the filter function

Comment: For some reason, when I test this, $.unique is not removing duplicate values. Perhaps it's because it sees a unique jQuery object containing all the duplicate values? However, I only need to check the first row for pattern matches, since all other cells in the same column are guaranteed to match the pattern. I can adapt what you've given me with that in mind.

Comment: Yeah--forget the $.unique call, it only works for arrays of DOM elements. Seemed to work ok in the JSFiddle I was experimenting in, but it must have been accidental.